# How to create a generic type with an overloaded specified constructor in F#

Tags: f#

I'd like to be able to define an F# type that is generic, but has an overload with a specified type. In particular, I'd like to define a chart plotting type, that takes a sequence of Xs, and a sequence of sequences of Ys, of any numerical type. However, if no Xs are supplied, I'd like to provide an automatic range of integers. The problem is that this breaks the genericness of my type. For the sample code is below, when I put in the overload, I get the following error: `Warning  2   This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'T has been constrained to be type 'int'.`

```
type Plot(X : seq<'T>, Y : seq<seq<'U>>) =

    // Other plotting code
    do printfn "I am a plotter"

    // Constructor overload for when no Xs are provided
    new (Y : seq<seq<'U>>) = let Xs = List.init (Seq.length Y) id
                             Plot(Xs, Y)
```

Additionally, `'U` has been constrained to type `obj`. Is there any way to do this without taking an `obj` and doing a coercion to `double`? I sense I am missing something fundamental about the type system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a static member. Also, the type args are missing from your type definition.

```
type Plot<'T, 'U>(X : seq<'T>, Y : seq<seq<'U>>) =

    // Other plotting code
    do printfn "I am a plotter"

    // Static member for when no Xs are provided
    static member Create<'V>(Y : seq<seq<'V>>) = 
        let Xs = List.init (Seq.length Y) id
        Plot(Xs, Y)
```

Comment: this is a good solution, but ideally I'd like to be able to do this with an overloaded constructor. It's mainly for scripting, and it would be be advantage if I could just throw the data in without thinking too much about separate methods.

Comment: It's not possible in a constructor, but you could overload `Create` and achieve the same effect.

Comment: This was the solution I went for in the end. A private constructor which takes a DU, and an overloaded `create` that calls it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the DU. The constructor you have handles both cases.